# Uploading an Image to IPFS using NFT.storage in JavaScript and Storing the CID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ipfs, nft

`Im working on a project where I need to allow users to upload an image, store it on IPFS using the NFT.storage service, and then store the resulting Content Identifier (CID) in a JavaScript variable for further use. I'm using React for my frontend.
I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.